# Does the API Platform framework fully support HATEOAS?

Tags: rest, hateoas, api-platform.com, hypermedia

Currently I am working on a REST API and noticed, that for real REST it is essential to provide the possible HTTP operations of the resource within the HTTP response (e.g. in JSON-LD format).

After playing around with Swagger, I got to JSON-LD and Hydra, which in combination provide the foundation for real REST.

The problem with pure JSON-LD and Hydra is, that there is no real editor (*the [Playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/) does help for testing but not for editing*).

Then I found [Api Platform](https://api-platform.com/) which sounds quite promising but I could not find any hint, that it supports real REST.

**Does API Platform support HATEOAS in terms of providing the possible HTTP operations?**

Answer (score 0):

API Platform explicitly supports HATEOAS and they even [encourage using Hydra](https://api-platform.com/docs/schema-generator/#be-ready-for-the-future). Their admin UI supports viewing the API through an OpenAPI lens or a Hydra lens.